# io.connect for nodejs in laravel

Tags: node.js, sockets, laravel

Hi I'm having a problem with my io.connect("mydomain:3000") (for my case I'm testing it on localhost so where "mydomain" is "http:// localhost") line on my laravel view file I am seeing error on my browser console like this one "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" but when I change my io.connect parameter to my IP address it worked very well but my problem is I don't really want to rely on my IP address so if anyone has a fix for this please help me. Thanks in advance!

By the way I'm using larval framework so I connected my socket.io.js file this way:

{{HTML::script("node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js")}}

Answer (score 0):

```
Whats your dns entry verify in /etc/hosts file ? if you are in UNIX like OS,
```

Check whether ping is Working for you by given domain name

```
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.096 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
```

Comment: Yep, ping is working for my localhost my project is still on localhost/xampp server.

PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.112 ms

Comment: i think I am connecting but somehow my socket.io.js file cannot be found- I'm receiving this error on my browser console:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1416387579313-11